# How does Heroku dyno caching works with Play framework

Tags: heroku, playframework

I have a Play application hosted by Heroku with 5 dynos. Its seems like my dynos were been restarted randomly in different time period. For example, three of them were restarted by itself 22 hours ago, and two of them were restarted 10 hours ago (not sure if this time was triggered by clearing the cache). It seems like that cached data isn't persistent between dynos. My problem is when I sent same request to my Heroku application multiple times, I get different cached response, in the response, some are most up to date data, others were old data. I assume this is because my request was processed by different dyno. After restart all my dyno fixed the problem(I assume this also clear cache in all dynos).

So I want to know what triggered the random dyno restart, and why it does that?

How to solve cached data inconsistency in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for dyno restarts, did you try the documentation?  Dyno's are cycled [at least once per day](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts)

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use mutualised cache in order to avoid this kind of problem when you scale horizontally.

Couchbase is a good solution to do it. We use this internally at Clever Cloud (http://www.clever-cloud.com/en/), that is the reason why we released a Couchbase as a service.